# Accessing instance functions inside controller from function on $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that looks like this:

```
function controller($scope)
{
  this.helper() = function()
  {
    // some processing
  };

  $scope.doSomething = function()
  {
    helper(); 
  };
}
```

When doSomething is called, I get an error saying that helper() is not defined. Putting 'this' in front of the call to helper() doesn't work either as 'this' here refers to $scope and not to the controller instance.

My question is: is there a way to call such local helper functions from within a function on the scope? (I know I could just put helper() on the $scope too but would rather not as it's strictly a convenience function, not something to be called from the view.)

The reason for structuring the code like this is to facilitate separate testing of the helper() function from a unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function controller($scope)
{
  this.helper() = function()
  {
    // some processing
  };
  var helperScope = this;

  $scope.doSomething = function()
  {
    helperScope.helper(); 
  };
}
```

Of course, give it a more descriptive name than that, but the basic idea is to assign `this` to a variable within the scope you want.

Comment: Thanks, that works, even if a bit messy. There's no way of asking angularjs for the current controller instance inside doSomething itself?

Comment: @ErikJ No, unfortunately JS does not have the ability to do that.